# Signing a webextension with node_module scripts using web-ext

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm using [web-ext](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/getting-started-with-web-ext/#Signing_your_extension_for_distribution) to sign an addon but I'm always having the same error message:

```
A content script defined in the manifest could not be found.
Error: Content script defined in the manifest could not be found at "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js".
```

I already tried to change the path in the `manifest.json file` with `./`, like:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": [
        "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

But the message keeps appearing, and it ignores the `./` since the message keeps complaining about `could not be found at "node_modules/...`.

Not sure if there is a way to clear the web-ext cache. Or what I'm doing wrong to include such scripts. It seems the problem is with node_modules scripts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you plan to include node_modules in the output extension? That's not how it's usually done. You either build the extension (using a build script) so all files are copied/bundled automatically or you copy the files from node_modules manually yourself.

Comment: @wOxxOm can you point me to a reference example of such script, please? Do you mean, using web-ext build... But it uses package.json config. And I don't know the format it should have to take sources fron node_modules and putting them somewhere else. There is no mention of that in the docs

Comment: I don't think this is a responsibility of web-ext. You need to do it in your main build script. Such a script usually copies/bundles the source files into a new directory like `dist` then optionally runs web-ext to produce the final xpi from that.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, I just created a separated node script :)